# Which exe is used In Visual Studio 2010 to run unit test dll

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have created a unit test in my c# project which builds into a dll file.Now i want to know which exe makes use of this dll to run unit tests.Is it mstest.exe or some other executable

Comment: It is QTAgent32 which uses this dll to run unit tests....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QTAgent32.exe is used by the microsoft etsting framework for testing purposes.MsTest.exe in turn calls QTAgent32.exe for running tests on agents....

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at NUnit http://www.nunit.org/  for unit testing. It's easy to setup and comes with a GUI for testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MS test framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486(v=vs.90).aspx